# CSS 404 Node.JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I have been trying for a long time to make the CSS file load. I have looked at other stackoverflow  questions and no luck. I have the express.static statements. I have the "standard" file order. It seems that I am doing something very very obvious wrong.

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="inline"><a class="inline" target="_blank" href="http://instagram.com/blakskyben/?hl=en">My Insta</a></li>
                <li class="inline"><a class="inline" href="/about">About Me</a></li>
                <li class="inline"><a class="inline" href="/">Blogs</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
___________________________________________________________________________
    var express = require("express"),
        app = express(),
        bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
        mongoose = require("mongoose");

    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/blog");

    var blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
         title: String,
         content: String
    });

    app.use(express.static("public"));
    app.use(express.static("partials"));

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    app.get("/",function(req,res){
        res.redirect("/blogs");
    });

    app.get("/blogs",function(req,res){
        blog.find({},function(err,foundBlogs){
            if(foundBlogs){
                res.render("blogs.ejs",{blogs: foundBlogs});
            } else {
                res.send("Sorry, an error occured retriving the blogs, " + err);
            }
        });
    });

    app.get("/blogs/:id",function(req,res){
        blog.findById(req.params.id,function(err,foundBlog){
            if(foundBlog){
                res.render("show.ejs",{blog: foundBlog});
            } else {
                res.send("Sorry, but there was an error, " + err);
            }
        });
    });

    app.get("/about",function(req,res){
        res.render("about.ejs");
    });

    var blog = mongoose.model("blog",blogSchema);

    //Seed the DB!

    blog.create({
        title: "Camp",
        content: "Blah." 
    });

    app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: Is `style.css` present in your project directory?

Comment: It is in the CSS folder that is inside the public folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the path to your static directories is wrong. Instead of

```
app.use(express.static("public"));
```

try

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the css path from application's root direcotry i.e

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
```

or if your CSS file is inside a folder, then

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/folderName/style.css">
```

whichever applicable for you.